# Name for a menu bar that stays as you browse?

Tags: drupal, menubar

I read a while ago there is a specific name for this. Let's say i'm on mysite.com, and I click on www.google.com, and when I get to google.com, there's a big MYSITE.com bar at the top, which easily allows me to go back to MYSITE.com. What is this called, and is there a plugin for this in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, above replies doesn't answer what you asked. Correct me if I'm wrong.

You are looking for a way to add an iframe toolbar just like about.com or images.google.com does.
You can do this with a raw HTML page that doesn't bootsrap Drupal at all.
You will find External Links module useful if you are willing to create a module.
See http://www.amirharel.com/2009/07/28/implementing-iframe-toolbar/ for HTML stuff.

Comment: There is a module called External Links that lets you open the external links (out side if the current domain. you can manually include domains as internal too. http://drupal.org/project/extlink). I think better modifying the module to support this. See http://drupal.org/node/134949 for an issue with a patch and this issue is still active.

Answer (score 5):

You may be referring to HTML frames?

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp

These usually perform badly with browser back-forward buttons though.

Comment: I don't think it's done with frames. But then again, I suppose there's no other way, hey?

Comment: @RD I would say that HTML frames are the "simplest" way. Surely not the only way, and definitely not the best way. I personally hate when sites use them because they tend to get nested erroneously and stick around when you don't want them anymore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure frames is the only way. All other methods would respect cross-site, hence it will not work if you leave your domain. Unless you load the whole site and push in into your site by javascript (jquery).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use frames! They're ugly, will confuse the users, and we're not in 1995 anymore ;)

What you're looking for is **CSS fixed menus**

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus.en.html

I never used **Drupal**, but I found that with a bit of googling: http://drupal.org/node/769848

Answer (score 3):

Google don't named it in their [press release](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/evolving-google-design-and-experience.html). A few days ago Google [get rid](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/next-stage-in-our-redesign.html) of the *black bar*. 
Drupal has at least two such modules:

- [Simple menu](http://drupal.org/project/simplemenu)
- [Administration menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu)

Answer (score 1):

Frame Google just because you think your users will search from there is not a good option, if that's what you are trying to do. That way you could think about framing Facebook and other valuable sites, but trust me, people don't like frames (I just hate them all!)

What you should do is to create a custom search engine for your site, and this is a valuable functionality from Google Search Engine to your users finding stuff on your site (only indexed pages).

If you are interested visit http://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely done with frames. Here is the relevant code from a Google Translation :

```
<frameset rows="65,*" frameborder="1" framespacing="0" cols="*">
     <frame src="/translate_n?act=url&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;prev=_t&amp;sl=auto&amp;tl=en&amp;u=http://lamaisonducinema.com/" name="n" scrolling="no" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
     <frame src="/translate_p?act=url&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;prev=_t&amp;sl=auto&amp;tl=en&amp;u=http://lamaisonducinema.com/&amp;usg=ALkJrhgchorYUw9YujsX2PFQ6ZZSxH4A1A" name="c">
     <noframes>&lt;script&gt;&lt;!--document.location="/translate_p?act=url&amp;amp;hl=en&amp;amp;ie=UTF8&amp;amp;prev=_t&amp;amp;sl=auto&amp;amp;tl=en&amp;amp;u=http://lamaisonducinema.com/&amp;amp;usg=ALkJrhgchorYUw9YujsX2PFQ6ZZSxH4A1A";--&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;a href="/translate_p?act=url&amp;amp;hl=en&amp;amp;ie=UTF8&amp;amp;prev=_t&amp;amp;sl=auto&amp;amp;tl=en&amp;amp;u=http://lamaisonducinema.com/&amp;amp;usg=ALkJrhgchorYUw9YujsX2PFQ6ZZSxH4A1A"&gt;Translate&lt;/a&gt;</noframes>
     <object style="padding: 0px !important;margin: 0px !important;background: transparent !important;position: fixed !important;border: none !important;-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;top: -100px !important;left: -100px !important;display: block !important;width: 1px !important;visibility: hidden !important;height: 1px !important;" data="safari-extension://com.interclue.ultimatestatusbar-725998GKSY/f41e051d/fixUninitalizedPage.html"></object>
</frameset>
```

For Drupal 6, it seems the Modal Frame module might do the trick : http://drupal.org/project/modalframe.

Answer (score 0):

They are called *fixed menus*.  Do not use frames.

HTML:

```
<header><p>I'm always at the top</p></header>
<article>
     <p>blah</p>
     <p>blah</p>
     <p>blah</p>
     <p>...</p>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
header { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
```